# I need to sum total_Amount where title =income and title=expense

Tags: sql, c#-3.0

I need to sum the total_amount according to the title. Actually i dont have relation among these two table but to take out the saving i need to sum them up and difference the sum of both totals.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpSavingDetail]
@year varchar(10),
@month varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @Saving int 

select e.Date_time as Date_time ,c.category as Particular,e.Description as Description ,e.Amount as Amount,
e.Frequency as Frequency,e.Total_Amount as Total_Amount,'Expense' as Title from tbl_expense as e
left join tbl_category as c on c.Cat_id=e.Cat_id where datepart(MM,e.Date_time)=@month and datepart(YYYY,e.Date_time)=@year
union 
select i.Date_time as Date_time ,s.source  as Particular,i.Description as Description ,i.Amount as Amount,
i.Frequency as Frequency,i.Total_Amount as Total_Amount,'Income' as Title from tbl_income as i
left join tbl_source as s on s.Source_id=i.Source_id
 where datepart(MM,i.Date_time)=@month and datepart(YYYY,i.Date_time)=@year





  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z5po.jpg
```

Comment: How is this C# code?

Comment: its storedprocedure which i use in report

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this language, (is it T-SQL?  You'll have more luck if you tag the question more appropriately) but you should be able to do something along the lines of the following:

```
declare @expense int 
declare @income int 

select @expense = SUM(e.Amount)
  from tbl_expense as e
 where datepart(MM,e.Date_time)=@month and datepart(YYYY,e.Date_time)=@year

select @income = SUM(i.Amount)
  from tbl_income as i
 where datepart(MM,i.Date_time)=@month and datepart(YYYY,i.Date_time)=@year

@Saving = @income - @expense
```

Comment: It gives error over into @expense saying expecting id

Comment: I've never used this language, so I may have made some incorrect assumptions.  I've amended the question – can you try this?

Comment: I m using sql server 2012

Comment: Actually i need all those fields mentioned above but using ur code it doesnt allow me to use ...

Comment: I tried to answer the specific question.  If you need the procedure to do multiple things, then you need code for all that.  You could have both versions: your sample for the data items, and mine for the totals.  It wouldn't be efficient, but might get you going. It's possible I'm misunderstanding.